# Is there a `man/` equivalent of $PATH (which is for extra `bin/` directories)?

Tags: path, man, apropos

When I experimentally install some new software, I don't go through the extra effort of putting all assets in the right places like `/usr/local/man`.

Occasionally, I'd like to have manpage support for it but I don't want to crowd my base Linux installation with it (after a few months, the new tool falls out of use). For binaries, this isn't a problem because $PATH can be appended to with wherever I've put my short/medium-term executable. But is there an equivalent for `man` assets?

(come to think of it, I'm not 100% sure what the difference between `doc` and and `man` is but I'm assuming `man` is what gets searched by `apropos`, which infuriatingly gives me zero results for almost everything)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out next time my head is in that space. https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/manpath.1.html . Feel free to post as an an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "equivalent" of `$PATH` is `$MANPATH`. See [`man 1 man`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lunar/en/man1/man.1.html#environment):

> `MANPATH`
>
> If `$MANPATH` is set, its value is used as the path to search for manual pages.
>
> See the SEARCH PATH section of `manpath(5)` for the default behaviour and details of how this environment variable is handled.

Maybe you don't need to use `$MANPATH`; consider relying on the default behaviour. The most relevant fragments of [`man 5 manpath`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lunar/en/man5/manpath.5.html#search%20path):

> By default, man-db examines the user's `$PATH`. For each `path_element` found there, it adds `manpath_element` to the search path.
>
> If there is no `MANPATH_MAP` line in the configuration file for a given `path_element`, then it adds all of `path_element/../man`,  `path_element/man`,  `path_element/../share/man`, and `path_element/share/man` that exist as directories to the search path.
>
> It then adds any `MANDATORY_MANPATH` entries from the configuration file to the search path.
>
> […]
>
> The `$MANPATH` environment variable overrides man-db's default manual page search paths. Most users should not need to set it. Its syntax is similar to the `$PATH` environment variable: it consists of a sequence of directory names separated by colons. It  overrides the default search path […].
>
> If the value of `$MANPATH` starts with a colon, then the default search path is added at its start. If the value of `$MANPATH` ends with a colon, then the default search path is added at its end. If the value of `$MANPATH` contains a double colon (`::`), then the default search path is inserted in the middle of the value, between the two colons.

There is also a command [`manpath`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lunar/en/man1/manpath.1.html). It may be useful in debugging your setup.

The links in this answer point to manpages of Ubuntu. In general refer to documentation and manuals of your specific distro.